# EM interference with hall effect sensor

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, electromagnetism

When using a hall effect sensor like [this one](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv5053.pdf), naturally, it will be pretty close to a rapidly changing magnetic field.  This means that the analog signal line coming out of the sensor will also be close to a rapidly changing magnetic field.  I'm concerned about shielding this analog signal from the very field that the hall effect sensor is trying to measure.  According to my back-of-the-envelope calcs, I shouldn't have to worry about this... can someone confirm my calculations?

---

I know that [Lenz's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law) tells us that induced voltage due to a changing B-Field is given by

[image]

and of course

[image]

Given the strength of the magnets in my physical setup and their position relative to my loop, I expect a maximum dB/dt of about 10Tesla / second.  My pcb is the standard 0.1524mm trace/space, so I could conservatively have the loop of "analog signal + return path" be on the order of 10^-5 square meters.

All of this suggests that even with a rapidly moving magnetic field, I will have less than 1 milliVolt of noise in my (very delicate) analog signal.

---

Is my analysis sane, or is EMI protection a problem when measuring a rapidly changing B-field with a hall effect sensor?

Comment: "Twisted pair" could be an approach to reduce loop area to almost 0.

Comment: @JimmyB Does that work with PCB traces on a PCB that is about 1.5mm thick?

Comment: Probably not. You'd have to wire the pins.